# Spark: How can I add the sizes of each RDD and write to a new file?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm saving each event in text file as follows:

```
map{ case (_, record) => getEventFromRecord(record) }.map(m => m.toByteArray).saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
```

I want to also save the total size of each event I'm saving to text file.
1) How can I save the total size of each record to a new file?
2) I tried using accumulator

```
val accum = sparkContext.accumulator(0, "My Accumulator")
map{ case (_, record) => getEventFromRecord(record) }.foreach(m => accum += (m.toByteArray.length)).saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
```

But I get the following error:

```
            value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Unit

[error]     sparkContext.sequenceFile(inputDirectory, classOf[IntWritable], classOf[DataOutputValue]).map{ case (_, record) => getEventFromRecord(record) }.foreach(m => accum += (m.toByteArray.length)).saveAsTextFile(outputPath)
[error]                                                                                                                                                                                                            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreach action returns unit as a result and is only used for side effects.  If you want to collect the sum of your rdd, use the `reduce` action

```
val totalSize = map{ case (_, record) => getEventFromRecord(record).toByteArray.length}.reduce{_ + _}
```

This will return the result of the summation on the driver.  You can then use the Hadoop Filesystem api to create a new file and write to it.

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val outputWriter = new PrintWriter(fs.create(outputPath))
outputWriter.println(totalSize)
outputWriter.flush()
outputWriter.close()
```

Note that in production you probably would want to wrap that outputstream into a try/catch/finally block or similar to make sure your resources close properly as with any file IO you do.

Comment: Thanks! But I don't think the above code works. I want to save the TOTAL length os all records in the output file. But the above code gave me multiple objects like this `[B@157ac242
[B@343b877f
[B@2a8481f5
[B@12a57ac4
[B@518ed200`

Comment: @Noname, Sorry I misunderstood your question.  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Is there any way I could make this an RDD and write to text file using `saveAsTextFile` ?

Comment: @NoName yes of course.  You can wrap `totalSize` into a `Seq` and call `scv.parallelize` to turn the sinlgeton value into an RDD then call `rdd.saveAsTextFile`.  This method has some problems though, it will probably be a bit slower as it means moving the data back to an executor and constructing an rdd (probably not a huge deal if it's just one value), and you will end up with outputPath being a directory with _SUCCESS and part files inside instead of just a single file.  Since you are just writing a single value from the driver to your file I think it makes more sense to just do it directly.